# How to vectorize multiple matrix multiplications in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

For a conceptual idea of what I mean, I have 2 data points:

```
x_0 = np.array([0.6, 1.4])[:, None]
x_1 = np.array([2.6, 3.4])[:, None]
```

And a 2x2 matrix:

```
y = np.array([[2, 2], [2, 2]])
```

If I perform `x_0.T @ y @ x_0`, I get `array([[ 8.]])`. Similarly, `x_1.T @ y @ x_1` returns `array([[ 72.]])`.

But is there a way to perform both of these calculations in one go, without a for loop? Obviously the speed-up here is negligible, but I am working with much more data points than presented here.

Comment: How are `x_`s stored?

Comment: They are column stacked. Each column holds the RGB values of a pixel, and there are `n` columns (for `n` pixels). Held in an `np.array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `x` as the column stacked version of `x_0`, `x_1` and so on, we can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ji,jk,ki->i',x,y,x)
```

With a mix of `np.einsum` and `matrix-multiplcation` -

```
np.einsum('ij,ji->i',x.T.dot(y),x)
```

As stated earlier, `x` was assumed to be column-stacked, like so :

```
x = np.column_stack((x_0, x_1))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [236]: x = np.random.randint(0,255,(3,100000))

In [237]: y = np.random.randint(0,255,(3,3))

# Proposed in @titipata's post/comments under this post
In [238]: %timeit (x.T.dot(y)*x.T).sum(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.45 ms per loop

# Proposed earlier in this post
In [239]: %timeit np.einsum('ji,jk,ki->i',x,y,x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 832 µs per loop

# Proposed earlier in this post
In [240]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ji->i',x.T.dot(y),x)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to work. I've taken a look over the documentation for `einsum` and I'm not yet understanding how it works, though it seems incredibly powerful. I'll continue to look over it. Similarly, is it possible to do this without `einsum`?

Comment: @KeirSimmons Clarify the doubt that I asked about under the question?

Comment: @KeirSimmons With extra memory requirements, an easier way would be - `(x.T.dot(y)*x.T).sum(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to do the operation `(x.T).dot(A).dot(x)` for all `x` that you have.

```
x_0 = np.array([0.6, 1.4])[:, None]
x_1 = np.array([2.6, 3.4])[:, None]
x = np.hstack((x_0, x_1)) # [[ 0.6  2.6], [ 1.4  3.4]]
```

The easy way to think about it is to do multiplication for all `x_i` that you have with `y` as

```
[x_i.dot(y).dot(x_i) for x_i in x.T]
>> [8.0, 72.0]
```

But of course this is not too efficient. However, you can do the trick where you can do dot product of `x` with `y` first and multiply back with itself and sum over column i.e. you manually do dot product. This will make the calculation much faster:

```
x = x.T
(x.dot(y) * x).sum(axis=1)
>> array([  8.,  72.])
```

**Note** that I transpose the matrix first because we want to multiply column of `y` to each row of `x`