# Select first elements that satisfy a condition in a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with shape [N,M,2]. I have a condition on the last index, i.e.

```
condition = matrix[:,:,0]**2 + matrix[:,:,1]**2 <1
```

Now, I would like to select the elements of matrix that satisfy this condition. If I blindly apply `matrix[condition]`, I obviously get a result with shape [something, 2], because otherwise it would not be a matrix.

My problem is that **I need to keep the shape** [N, ..., 2]. For example, **it would be fine to take only the first K elements that satisfy the condition** (supposing that there are always at least K). How can I do this?

With a for loop I would write

```py
matrix_new = np.zeros([N,K,2])
for i in range(N):
    condition = matrix[i,:,0]**2 + matrix[i,:,1]**2 <1
    matrix_new[i] = matrix[condition][:K]
```

but this would be very slow. How can I avoid the for loop?

Comment: try to vectorize your code. see this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369976/how-to-vectorize-multiple-matrix-multiplications-in-numpy

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. You cannot simply have shape [N, ..., 2] for ones that meet condition simply because there might be different number of elements in each row that meet the condition and therefore the output will not be rectangular, hence numpy cannot create an array out of it. Do you mean to leave the elements that do not meet the condition with a default value, like 0?

Comment: @Ehsan I see your point now. Yes, I assumed the OP wanted the fails to be replaced with zeros, otherwise the OP would just want the matrix[cond] by itself.

Comment: No, I don't want to replace with zeros. I want to exclude the items that are not satisfied. to get a matrix, i would like to take the 'first K' elements that satisfy the condition (suppose that there are always at least K)

Comment: @AmitGupta but that's the question, how can I vectorize this?

Answer (score 0):

You already carved out your new space. You just need to save your conditioned matrix to it:

```
matrix           = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[0,1]]])
cond             = matrix[...,0]**2+matrix[...,1]**2 < 10 
matrix_new       = np.zeros([3,2,2])
matrix_new[cond] = matrix[cond]
```

Remember that array[cond] returns a view in numpy, before the result. Hence, numpy has a few tricks up it's sleeve and will cast to what you save before returning the simplified array. :-)

EDIT:

The only thing I could find would be np.take_along_axis and the np.argsort methods for taking particular vectors in a particular order based on a conditional matrix. Something like:

```
matrix     = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,1],[5,6]],[[7,8],[0,1]]])
cond       = matrix[...,0]**2 + matrix[...,1]**2
matrix_new = np.take_along_axis(matrix,cond.argsort()[...,None],axis=1)

matrix_new[:,0,:] #Smallest vectors in each. 
matrix_new[:,1,:] #Second smallest vectors in each.
```

Also, you can get the value K with "K = max((cond < 10).sum(1))".

Comment: This will leave the ones that do not meet the condition as zeros.

Comment: I am not following what you mean. What else did you want them to be?

Comment: This is not my question and the question does not state what it intends to do with them. I was not criticizing your answer. Simply a comment to note that for the reader.

Comment: @Ehsan Also my bad, didn't realize you were not the OP.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I can throw away the extra items - for example I would take the matrix that takes the minimum of the satisfied constrains in a single row. Does this clarify?

Comment: I am not following. If you don't want zeros to fill in, then how is matrix[cond] itself not the answer you are looking for? Can you give a concrete example of what you want?

Comment: for each row of the matrix, I will have a different number of element that satisfy the condition. So matrix[cond] won't have N rows, but N*something items, where N*something is the total number of elements that satisfied the constraint. I need to keep the rows.

Comment: To put it in another way, if you put zeros when the constraint is not satisfied to keep a matrix of shape [N,M,2], I would need the zeros to be at the end, so that all the elements of the matrix [N, :K,2] satisfy the constraint

Comment: It would be really helpful to have a concrete example, instead of trying to read between the lines. Can you take my example above with matrix_new and write out what you want it to look like?

Comment: @BobbyOcean With `matrix           = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,1],[5,6]],[[7,8],[0,1]]])` in your code,
I would like matrix_new =  `array([[[1., 2.]], [[1., 1.]],  [[0., 1.]]])`
(in this case K=1)

Comment: That isn't my matrix, you changed the entry [3,4] to a [1,1], which makes a big difference. This is exactly the point, how would you like to resolve the ambiguity of some vectors working and others not across the dimensions. I am starting to think that Ehsan was correct that you are asking for non rectangular answer which isn't possible.

Comment: Can you specify how the array np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[0,1]]]) should be transformed?

Comment: That should not happen, since in that case the minimum number of elements that satisfy the constraint in each row is K=0. It means I want the empty matrix in your particular case

Comment: In that case, you are definitely wanting to produce a non-rectangular answer. The only thing I can think of is to sort your results, not sure if that will speed up your code or not, since sorting is a non-trivial task. But could still be faster than a loop.

Comment: Maybe something like `np.argpartition(~cond, K)[:,K]` would work for the rectangular case in place of `argsort`? Should be faster too.

Comment: Ya, the argpartition function is probably better.